# Does a .getIntent() Bundle works when you don't initiate the activity right away?

Tags: java, android, bundle

This may be a noob question, but I've been searching for some explanation about it and wasn't able to find.

Well I have the A.class which is initiating an activity (A).

The user click in a button and we go to B.class, which also initiates a layout and I'm sending a `putExtra("key",value)` to the activity (B).

I receive it and works perfect!
Then I want to send a `putExtra("key",value)` back again to activity (A), but the user clicked in another button I started the C.class to do a background task of what he needs.

When the user goes back to activity (A), the `getIntent().getExtras()` is empty.

So my question is, changing classes (threads) or activities can mess your bundle?
Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're very confused.  The intent returned by getIntent is the Intent that started your activity.  It will never change.  If you have an Activity A that wants to start Activity B and get a result, Activity A must call startActivityForResult to start B, and B must set a *new* intent to be returned, call setResult, and then finish.  THen onActivityResult in Activity A will be called, and passed the result set by B.  The getIntent() will not return any results.

Comment: Well explained Gabe, I dind't know about the startActivityForResult method or to return something by setResult! Thanks a lot!!